# Python replace/remove substring from input string with a loop and mutating the original string with each iteration

Tags: python, string, function, replace, mutation

I am looking to process an input (string) and remove any items that follow the pattern of being encased in square brackets e.g [like this].

I have been able to identify the pattern which allows me to isolate and create a list of all occurences of square brackets in the string. using regex.

However I would like to replace these occurances and mutate the original string each time to replace the squared brackets with "" to remove them from the original string.

As I understand string.replace("example","") returns a copy of the original string.

How would I go about a technique to remove each occurence and then return the mutated input string.

My code for this function so far, is as follows.

```
def remove_square_brackets(input):
  """remove square brackets e.g [verse] from song lyrics """
  pattern1 = r"\[.*?\]" 
  squares = re.findall(pattern1, input) #this works, here we have seperated by chorus verse. 
  #can also be used to remove these bookmarks from the phrases themselves. 
  print("squares are", squares) #this is picking up all the squares
  for square in squares:
        print(square)
        if square in input:
             print("found in the string!")
             #replace does not mutate, rather it makes a copy therefore this will not work,. 
             input.replace(square,"")
  return input
```

Comment: "and mutate the original string" `str` objects are immutable, but you don't *need* to mutate it here.

Comment: Just assign the result back to the original variable `string = string.replace(...)`

Comment: Any reason you're using a loop with `.replace()` instead of `re.sub()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reassign the changed string to the input variable inside the loop using input = input.replace(square, ""). This ensures that each occurrence of the brackets is removed one at a time from the input variable and that the final result is returned correctly.

```
import re


def remove_square_brackets(input):
    """Remove square brackets e.g [verse] from song lyrics."""

    # Define the regular expression pattern to match square brackets and the text inside them.
    pattern1 = r"\[.*?\]"

    # Find all occurrences of the pattern1 in the input string using regular expression.
    squares = re.findall(pattern1, input)

    # Iterate through each occurrence of square brackets in the input string.
    for square in squares:
        # Print the square bracket occurrence found in the input string.
        print(square, "found in string!")

        if square in input:
            # Replace the square bracket occurrence and reassign it to the input variable.
            input = input.replace(square, "")

    # Return the modified input string with square brackets removed.
    return input


# Example usage:
lyrics = "This is [verse] some [chorus] example [bridge] lyrics."
result = remove_square_brackets(lyrics)
print(result)
```

**this is the output:**

```
[verse] found in string!
[chorus] found in string!
[bridge] found in string!
This is  some  example  lyrics.
```

Answer (score 0):

### Remove all lyrics section headings enclosed in brackets

#### Lyrics (example)

```py
lyrics = """[Verse 1]
I'm the next act waiting in the wings
I'm an animal trapped in your hot car
I am all the days that you choose to ignore

[Chorus]
You are all I need
You're all I need
I'm in the middle of your picture
Lying in the reeds

[Verse 2]
I am a moth who just wants to share your light
I'm just an insect trying to get out of the night
I only stick with you because there are no others

[Chorus]
You are all I need
You're all I need
I'm in the middle of your picture
Lying in the reeds

[Outro]
It's all wrong, it's all wrong, it's all wrong
It's alright, it's alright, it's alright
It's all wrong, it's alright
It's alright, it's alright"""
```

If I understand what output you're trying to get and you want to entirely remove all lyrics headings enclosed in brackets, then the pattern you have is perfect and this code will work:

```py
import re

def get_lyrics_headings(lyrics):
    """Return all instances of headings (e.g., '[Chorus]') from song lyrics."""
    return re.findall(r"\[.*\]", lyrics)

def remove_square_brackets(lyrics):
    """Remove square brackets (e.g '[verse]') from song lyrics."""
    headings = get_lyrics_headings(lyrics)
    print(f"Found the following lyrics sections:\n{headings}")
    return re.sub(r"\[.*\]", "", lyrics)
```

which yields:

```py
>>> raw_lyrics = remove_square_brackets(lyrics)
```

```
Found the following lyrics sections:
['[Verse 1]', '[Chorus]', '[Verse 2]', '[Chorus]', '[Outro]']
```

```py
>>> print(raw_lyrics)
```

```
I'm the next act waiting in the wings
I'm an animal trapped in your hot car
I am all the days that you choose to ignore


You are all I need
You're all I need
I'm in the middle of your picture
Lying in the reeds


I am a moth who just wants to share your light
I'm just an insect trying to get out of the night
I only stick with you because there are no others


You are all I need
You're all I need
I'm in the middle of your picture
Lying in the reeds


It's all wrong, it's all wrong, it's all wrong
It's alright, it's alright, it's alright
It's all wrong, it's alright
It's alright, it's alright
```

### Replace brackets with double quotes

You'll want to change your regular expression pattern slightly, if you want to replace lyrics brackets ("[" or "]") with double quotes (such as '[Chorus]' becoming → '"Chorus"').

For example:

```py
import re

def remove_square_brackets(lyrics):
    """Remove square brackets (e.g '[verse]') from song lyrics."""
    return re.sub(r"\[|\]", '"', lyrics)
```

will result instead in:

```
"Verse 1"
I'm the next act waiting in the wings
I'm an animal trapped in your hot car
I am all the days that you choose to ignore

"Chorus"
You are all I need
You're all I need
I'm in the middle of your picture
Lying in the reeds

"Verse 2"
I am a moth who just wants to share your light
I'm just an insect trying to get out of the night
I only stick with you because there are no others

"Chorus"
You are all I need
You're all I need
I'm in the middle of your picture
Lying in the reeds

"Outro"
It's all wrong, it's all wrong, it's all wrong
It's alright, it's alright, it's alright
It's all wrong, it's alright
It's alright, it's alright
```

Answer (score 0):

`str.replace()` function in Python does not mutate the original string, but instead returns a new string with the replacements. This is because strings in Python are immutable once they are created they cannot be changed.

you can reassign the returned value back to your original variable to achieve the effect of "mutating" the original string as below ,

```
import re

def remove_square_brackets(input):
  """remove square brackets e.g [verse] from song lyrics """
  pattern1 = r"\[.*?\]" 
  squares = re.findall(pattern1, input) #this works, here we have seperated by chorus verse. 
  #can also be used to remove these bookmarks from the phrases themselves. 
  print("squares are", squares) #this is picking up all the squares
  for square in squares:
        print(square)
        if square in input:
             print("found in the string!")
             #replace does not mutate, rather it makes a copy therefore this will not work,. 
             input = input.replace(square,"")
  return input
```

you can simplify your function,as there is no need to separately find and then replace the occurrences of the pattern. You could directly use the re.sub() function to substitute all occurrences of the pattern with an empty string.

```
import re

def remove_square_brackets(input):
  """remove square brackets e.g [verse] from song lyrics """
  pattern1 = r"\[.*?\]" 
  # Substitute all occurrences of the pattern with an empty string.
  input = re.sub(pattern1, "", input)
  return input
```

This function will behave exactly the same as the previous version but with less code and potentially faster execution especially for large inputs as it only needs to scan the input string once.